# Integral for a conservative vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, parametrization, line-integrals

I'd like some guidance on how to solve this problem.

> Given vector field: $$ \vec{F}  = <y \cos(xy), x \cos(xy), \frac{1}{1+z^2} >$$ and I need to compute the integral $ \int_{C}  \vec{F}.d\vec{r} $ for $C$ that is the curve given by the cylinder with radius $1$ and that connects points $P_0=(1,0,1),P_1= (0,1,0)$.

What I did was parametrize $r(t) :x = r\cos(t), y=r\sin(t), z=t$, with $r=1$ and defining $0 \leq t \leq 1$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ as it's what made most sense given the points.
But now I am left with a monster of a line integral when I parametrize $\vec F( r(t))$. What am I missing here? Or is this the way it should go?

Comment: You yourself said the vector field is conservative. Do you know any facts/theorems about the line integral of a conservative field?

Comment: I will use $d\vec r = d\vec s$ to avoid confusion. Let $\vec r$ be the position vector, so the path is $\vec s = \vec r$ and $d\vec s = \vec v dt$, where $\vec v$ is the velocity. Assuming mass is constant, we get 
$$m\int_{C}\dot v v dt$$
Note that $\frac{d}{dt}(v^2) = 2\dot v v$, so $\dot v v = \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt}(v^2)$
$$m\int_{C}\dot v v dt = \frac{m}{2}\int_{C}\frac{d}{dt}(v^2) dt$$ Could this help in any way?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, as for some reason we completely skipped the chapters on velocity and acceleration. @RyanShesler

Comment: If you covered potentials, then you could use the fact that if the field is conservative then $F = - \nabla V$ for some scalar potential $V$ dependent only on the starting and end positions of a particle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you manage to find a "potential function" for $F$, or more precisely, a function $f: \Bbb{R^3} \to \Bbb{R}$ such that $\nabla f = \vec{F}$, then your integral depends only on the endpoints of the path (there is a famous theorem guaranteeing this.,which one?) So now,
\begin{equation}
\int_C \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r} = \int_C \nabla f \cdot d\vec{r} = f(0,1,0) - f(1,0,1)
\end{equation}
(the last equality is true if the curve $C$ starts at $P_0$ and ends at $P_1$; otherwise there will be an overall minus sign on the RHS)

Now, all that's left is to find an appropriate $f$. My hint to you for this is to think about trigonometric functions.

Comment: Yeah it finally clicked, so it is indeed conservative because of the energy conservation law, so finding the suitable f as $sin(xy)+arctan(z)$ it appears that the answer is $-(-45°)$ or $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: @JúlioCezar for the $f$ you have mentioned, we have $f(0,1,0) = 0$, while $f(1,0,1) = \frac{\pi}{4}$. So the difference should be $0 - \frac{\pi}{4} = - \frac{\pi}{4}$ (as I said, assuming we start at $P_0$ and end at $P_1$)

Comment: Correct, and that is what I assume as well. However, seeing as there is no negative result among the possible answers in the sheet, it seems to be the other way around.

Comment: The problem is that force is the **negative** potential of a scalar function. For example, if I apply a negative force against gravity, there is a positive increase in gravitational potential energy

Comment: If you could, please check the $f$ I found to see if I made no mistakes (but assuming that taking partial derivatives and comparing to the initial $F$ is proofreading enough, I don't believe it is wrong), but as I said, the answers indeed are all positive. Whether the answers are correct or not, though, is a whole different problem.

Comment: @RyanShesler Defining force to be negative gradient of  a scalar function is simply a physics convention so that it aligns with our everyday interpretation of potential. The choice of minus sign has no mathematical meaning. If you define $f(x,y,z) = \sin(xy)+ \arctan(z)$ as suggested above, and compute its gradient, you will indeed find that $\nabla f = \vec{F}$, so the equalities I wrote are correct. If you insist on writing $\vec{F} = -\nabla U$, for some scalar $U$, then you will have to define $U(x,y,z) = -(\sin(xy) + \arctan(z))$. So $U = -f$, which again, doesn't change the final answer.

Comment: The convention that Goldstein uses in *Classical Mechanics*, which I learned from, is  $\vec F = - \nabla V$, and I was just trying to point out to the op why $\frac{\pi}{4}$ is the available answer on his sheet. I wasn't judging the validity of your answer

Comment: @RyanShesler Yes, and I agree with you on that; I learnt from Goldstein as well. My point is that in this question, there is no reason to even think of $\vec{F}$ as being a force, and that the choice of - sign is purely to associate physical meaning to $V$. My best guess is either the point $P_0$ and $P_1$ have been mislabelled, or the curve $C$ is oriented the other direction, or simply the answers given there are wrong. Anyway I think we are getting off track because clearly the purpose of this question is to use the fundamental gradient theorem, rather than explicit parametrisation.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $\vec F = m \vec a$, $\vec v = \int \vec a dt$, and the field is conservative. From my comment, I left off at
$$\frac{m}{2} \int_{C} \frac{d}{dt}((\vec{v})^2) dt$$
Because the field is conservative, $\vec F$ can be derived from a scalar potential $V$ dependent only on the intial and final positions of the particle in the following way: $\vec F = -\nabla V$. Thus, the line integral is independent of the path, $C$, and it takes the form $\frac{m}{2}(v_2 ^2 - v_1 ^2)$, where $v_2,v_1$ are the final and initial velocities, respectively. Now take your formula for $\vec F$ and multiply by a $\frac{1}{m}$ term to each component ($\frac{1}{m} \vec F = \vec a$), and treat it like a constant. Integrate your new force vector with respect to time to get the velocity vector and plug in the final and initial values into the formula above.